# Sugar CRM - creating new module using module builder

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

I wanted to create a new module in my copy of Sugar CRM. I selected a package, and went to create a new module (using module builder). The last field in the form asks to select a module type . If we select module type, say, user, then around 10-15 fields comes up in the module. These cannot be edited. But I wanted to create a module which would consists of only those elements I wanted to. So is there any way to create a new module without having those fields?

For example, I wanted to create a module called 'donation' which would contain the list of all donations made by the users (1 'User' can make MANY 'donation'). Since user field will
always contain all the user detail (example, first name, last name, email etc), so we do not repeat them for each donations made by the user. So donation module should contain only field like

```
["user-id", "donation-amount", "payment-method", "cc-number"].
```

Any Sugar usercan help me in this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply hide the unwanted fields on the various views. Some of these fields are basically required by the framework in one way or another (name, date_modified, etc). But it doesn't mean that you need to utilize them. The other additional fields could be removed from the vardefs.php if desired, but it isn't worth the hassle usually.